# Isolating text in a large xml file

Tags: xml, replace, notepad++

It's my first time asking for help here so pls don't eat me.

I have a really big and messy .xml file on my hands. Its structure goes like this:

```
<SPEAKER N°001>ERROR</SPEAKER N°001>
<ORIGINAL N°001>
TEXT THAT INTERESTS ME1
TEXT THAT INTERESTS ME1
</ORIGINAL N°001>
<JAPANESE N°001>
ツートンカラーの群れはグルグルと回り続け、
三方向から催眠動画を見せられているかのような錯覚に
陥る戦刃だが、それでも、彼女の表情は凍ったままだ。
</JAPANESE N°001>
<TRANSLATED N°001>

</TRANSLATED N°001>
<COMMENT N°001>

</COMMENT N°001>
------------------------------------------------------------
<SPEAKER N°002>ERROR</SPEAKER N°002>
<ORIGINAL N°002>
TEXT THAT INTERESTS ME2
</ORIGINAL N°002>
<JAPANESE N°002>
寧ろ、この異様な状況を前に、【超高校級の軍人】は
一際心が平静になりつつある。
</JAPANESE N°002>
<TRANSLATED N°002>

</TRANSLATED N°002>
<COMMENT N°002>

</COMMENT N°002>
------------------------------------------------------------
```

This repeats about hundred times. I need to isolate the text in <ORIGINAL N°*number*> tags and delete everything else, so the end result looks like this:

```
TEXT THAT INTERESTS ME1
TEXT THAT INTERESTS ME1
TEXT THAT INTERESTS ME2
...
TEXT THAT INTERESTS ME254
```

I had an idea to use a macro and search/replace function, but I can't for the life of me get it to work. The file is too long to do it manually. I'm using notepad++, but let me know if it's easier to do with different program.

Also, sorry if this question is a duplicate.

Comment: What you have is similar to XML, but it is is not real XML. Where does the file come from?

Comment: Files of an old video game. It does have .XML extension.

Comment: Having an XML extension doesn't make it XML unfortunately. You will have to use non-XML tools to process this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:(?!<ORIGINAL.+?>).)*<ORIGINAL.+?>\R*((?:(?!</ORIGINAL.+?>).)+)(?:</ORIGINAL.+?>(?:(?!<ORIGINAL.+?>).)*)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/VYDZPH/1)

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Piece of cake in powershell :)

Also: Your XML is invalid.

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Type `powershell`
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd>, a blue window appears. If not you are likely on linux :P
- Type the line below, but replace `D:\t.txt` with your path:

```bsh
(Get-Content D:\t.txt -Raw ) | Select-String -Pattern "(?smi)<ORIGINAL.*?>(.*?)</ORIGINAL" -AllMAtches | % {$_.Matches} | %{$_.Groups[1].ToString().Trim()}
```

My output was

```
TEXT THAT INTERESTS ME1
TEXT THAT INTERESTS ME1
TEXT THAT INTERESTS ME2
```